# how can I disable the debug messages in the console after firebase serve?

Tags: firebase, terminal, console, disable, serve

I have an index.html and about.html hosted on firebase. They have a link to each other.
When I type 'firebase serve' in the terminal, everything goes as intended, but as I start clicking links on index.html a bunch of debug messages appear in the console. After that I need to reopen it to use it again..
So any idea how to disable them??

Comment: Hi! Could you please provide some more information? What  are those debug messages like?

Comment: ok I addded a screenshot (idk why it is so bright)

Comment: These logs are not causing any crashing. Maybe it's something inside your html/js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This logs can't be disabled in the console, although you can filter them when using the emulator UI. There you can filter the logs you wish to see.

There was a feature request for this, and was marked as "closed" because you can "hide" these logs with filters. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1839

EDIT: this is the newest feature request that would allow behavior you refer to https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2859